# Make custom Burn-down chart + TFS 2017 +Release wise

Tags: visualization, tfs-workitem, burndowncharts

I see sprint burndown chart at the right-top corner of "Work -> backlog" page. I want a similar burn-down chart for release and project level. I wrote a query which gets the necessary workitems. I'm not able to depict them on a chart with "ideal trend" line, and release duration(maybe with sprint duration in middle.)

My chart just shows until the current date(stacked area chart has "Rolling period".). I want a chart with empty space from the current date to end date(like in sprint burn-down chart) with various status(new, active, closed) for workitems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't possible with the Work Item Visualization/Graphing features. There are [better burndown visualizations available on Visual Studio Team Services, but these depend on the Analytics Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=vsts#nbspnbspnbspburndown-chart), which, unfortunately, isn't available on TFS at the moment.

Right now your out-of-the-box supported solution is to use the Report Server Capability in TFS. If your admin has installed these. The experience of creating those types of reports and integrating things like sprint dates, team membership and capacity as well as days off is hard. Many of these data points aren't available in Report Server.

If you're unable to move to VSTS and if waiting until the end of the year isn't worth it, you could always opt for a solution that uses the REST API and host that on a separate web application, then iframe that into your dashboards. Or you could write a custom UI extension that does the same thing.

The [Analytics service and the widgets you're looking ("Dashboards - Sprint Burndown Widget based on Analytics")for are currently targetted for the TFS 2019 release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/).